# How to get all the google search results from its api in php?

Tags: php

im using this code:

```
function doGoogleSearch($searchTerm)
  {
   //$cx="002000009380213215808:hf9v-g9oyho";        
    $endpoint = 'web';
    $key= 'XXX';
    $url = "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/".$endpoint;

    $args['q'] = $searchTerm;
    $args['v'] = '1.0';

    $url .= '?'.http_build_query($args, '', '&');

    $ch = curl_init()or die("Cannot init");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);        
    $body = curl_exec($ch)or die("cannot execute");
    curl_close($ch);
    //decode and return the response
    return json_decode($body,1);
  }
```

By using this i just got the 1'st 4 results from it.Is there is any way to get the whole search result of google?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://pear.php.net/package/Services_Google

but google only access you for limited search

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out [in the Google Web Search API Class Reference](http://code.google.com/apis/websearch/docs/reference.html) you can use `rsz = 8` to get 8 results at a time and `start = xxx` to change the "page" of the results (i.e. get the next set of 8)

There is no way to get more than 8 results at a time, and the maximum number of results returned is 64 (see explanation [here](http://groups.google.com/group/Google-AJAX-Search-API/browse_thread/thread/db6616286ce83ca0#) and, again, [in the Class Reference](http://code.google.com/apis/websearch/docs/reference.html)).

Also, the Web Search API is deprecated, you should use the [Custom Search API](http://code.google.com/apis/customsearch/v1/overview.html) instead.

Comment: oh it worked well.but how can use start here?is it like this start=xxx?

Comment: now got .thanx alot.i can chang the value of start to get the whole result.

Comment: i got maximum 64 results by using this after that i got an error message like this:Array ( [responseData] => [responseDetails] => out of range start [responseStatus] => 400 )

Comment: @sirin k: That's the maximum you can get. See for instance: http://groups.google.com/group/Google-AJAX-Search-API/browse_thread/thread/db6616286ce83ca0# In particular, check out Jeremy Geerdes answer, and the references to Google TOS. (I will edit my answer to include these informations)